# How can I make a v-tooltip interactive?

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, tooltip, vuetify.js

I want that if I hover to the tooltip box it doesn't disappear, rather stay there so I can copy the text inside it.

```html
<v-tooltip right>
    <template v-slot:activator="{ on }">
        <a :href="getUrl(props.item)" target="_blank"><span v-on="on">{{renderData(props.item, header)}}</span></a>
    </template>
    <div>
        <span>Application Name: {{props.item.ApplicationName}}</span>
        <br />
        <span>Email: {{props.item.CustomerEmailAddress}}</span>
        <br />
        <span>Instance link: {{props.item.AppUrl}}</span>
    </div>
</v-tooltip>
```

[image: Sample result of the tooltip]

I want to be able to copy letter C in this case.
I am triggering the tooltip by hover.

Comment: According to vuetify document you can use v-model to bind a boolean value to v-tooltip to control it `<v-tooltip v-model="show">`, this may be helpful.

Comment: I have read about it and it doesn't work in my case.

Comment: Why would it not work

Comment: If you can do it please write it down in the answers section, thank you.

Comment: Are you triggering the tooltip on click or on hover? Are you using Vuetify 2.0 or 1.5?

Comment: Vuetify 2.0 and on hover.